# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

Tags: pandas, data-science-model, matplotlib

I have written this code

`fig, (axis1, axis2,axis3, axis4)=plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,4))`

and I am getting this error

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)`

I tried many ways to remove this error but all was in vain.
Can you explain to me why I am getting this error?

Comment: try: `x = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,4)); print(x)`.  what does it say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because you have not looked how the values are packed in `plt.subplot` function.

```
>>> plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,4))
(<matplotlib.figure.Figure at 0xa3918d0>, array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000000A389470>,
     <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000000A41AD30>],
    [<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000000A6F7EB8>,
     <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x000000000BC232E8>]], dtype=object))
```

Instead of unpacking all values at once, unpack in steps. You will get a better idea then.

For your solution, to unpack -

```
>>> fig, [[axis1, axis2],[axis3, axis4]] = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,4))
```

Answer (score 1):

The second return value will be a 2x2 array.  Try this.

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2,figsize=(10,4))
```